# How to setting http thread pool max size on quarkus

Tags: java, http, threadpool, quarkus

Sorry, I'm not really know about http thread pool how work on Quarkus.

I want setting http thread pool max size, But I see the [Quarkus doc](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config) have a lot config property about thread.

I try setting each that and check it working or not on prometheus. but prometheus base_thread_max_count always not match my config.

So, I want know how setting and check that.
Thanks so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the pool that handles HTTP I/O events only, then that's `quarkus.http.io-threads`

If you mean the worker pool that handles blocking operations, that's `quarkus.vertx.worker-pool-size`

The metric `base_thread_max_count` isn't really relevant to this, it shows you the maximum number of threads ever being active in that JVM, so it takes into account various threads unrelated to the HTTP layer. To see the number of active IO threads, I'd suggest taking a thread dump and counting the threads named `vert.x-eventloop-thread-*`, for worker threads it is `executor-thread-*`.

Also bear in mind that worker threads are created lazily, so setting a high number to `quarkus.vertx.worker-pool-size` might not have any immediate effect.

Comment: Hi, first thanks so much you answer, such as I have a few Resource Class provide RESTFul service,I want can receive many HTTP request than default, I should setting quarkus.http.io-threads?

Comment: If  the REST services do a lot of long-running synchronous operations, then you might need to increase `quarkus.vertx.worker-pool-size`, because these threads handle the long running operations. If you have a high amount of HTTP requests but they don't necessarily take long to handle (or are asynchronous), you might need to increase `quarkus.http.io-threads`

Comment: Thanks you so much. I will try it.

Comment: @JanMartiška What is the recommended worker-pool-size for the application running longer IO operations on k8s pod (1 cpu/2 GB mem) with Blocking annotation ? Any recommendations?